# Magento Chinese Locale is not showing

Tags: php

We are using Magento Enterprise edition. We can not see the Chinese language option in locale (System -> Configuration -> General -> Locale Options -> Locale). As shown in the attached picture. Can you please help me why it is not showing?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Go to the bottom of the list and it will be there:

*zhongwen (zhongguo) / Chinese (China)*

**zhongwen** and **zhongguo** will be in Chinese Characters (magento.stackexchange doesn't let us post those characters for now)

[image: Language Selection]